# Get CPU load percentage on Windows 2008r2 Server - WMIC doesn't work?

Tags: cpu-usage, wmic

I found the command `wmic cpu get LoadPercentage`  was [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097067/get-cpu-usage-from-windows-command-prompt) as a way to get a CPU load estimate from a command line.

It works as expected from a Windows 10 system:

```
c:\>wmic cpu get LoadPercentage
LoadPercentage
21

c:\>
```

From a Windows 2008r2 server, it doesn't return a value:

```
c:\>wmic cpu get LoadPercentage
LoadPercentage


c:\>
```

What can be done to allow this to work, or to get the data another way? I tried some of the other approaches in the referenced article and they didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Powershell : [How do I find the CPU and RAM usage using PowerShell?](https://newbedev.com/how-do-i-find-the-cpu-and-ram-usage-using-powershell)

---

***Powershell :***

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average
```

---

***Batch :***

```
@echo off
Title Get CPU load percentage
:Loop
cls
Powershell -C "Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average"
Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak>nul
Goto Loop
```

Comment: The Powershell command you show does not work on Windows Server 2008r2. It runs but returns nothing. 
After some trial and error, I found this commmand works: `(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).LoadPercentage`
From Windows CMD, I can run it as `powershell (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).LoadPercentage`
It returns a single number, which appears to be the CPU Load Percentage. It is not exactly what Resource Monitor shows, but close enough.